# How to handle unknown child routes with wildcard in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing, app-route

I need help with routing today. I've a set of components each with a different route. I want to add 'PageNotFoundComponent' for wildcard route in parent as well as child. What I mean is, this is my URL:

`http://localhost:8888/programs/cohorts`

`cohorts` is a child of `programs`. I want to redirect to `PageNotFoundComponent` when either `programs` or `cohorts` is wrong. Here is my code:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '',
        component: ProgramsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        children: [
            {
                path: 'programs/:dashboardId',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'programs/:dashboardId/:subPageId',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'programs/**',
                component: PageNotFoundComponent 
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: [DashboardModelResolver, DashboardListResolver]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I'm making mistake somewhere. Please point out and help me.

This is working perfectly fine: `http://localhost:8888/prrrooogrm/cohorts`

But this is giving blank screen: `http://localhost:8888/programs/cooohrt`

I tried this also:

```
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    RouterModule.forChild([
        {
            path: '**',
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ])
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Url `http://localhost:8888/programs/cooohrt` is matched by `programs/:dashboardId`

So blank screen is probaly result of `DashboardComponent`

If you want to match id to valid object you can use RouteGuard
or simply redirect from your component when you realize that object doesn't exist

```
this.router.navigate(['404-not-found'], { skipLocationChange });
```

skipLocationChange is there to keep original (wrong) url to be visible for user. '404-not-found' is simply anything which is not matched by any url (to be correct matched by your wildcard url)

Comment: How to do that. Please elaborate your answer

Comment: the easiest way is to use navigate on Router without location change, see extended answer

Comment: That is fine but where do i put that line. in which file or module

Comment: put it to DashboardComponent where you are using :dashboardId. when dashboardId is unexpected then route to not found

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'not-found',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: There's no path like `not-found` in my case.

Comment: post details of PageNotFoundComponent